# $\int g d\nu = \int fg d\mu$ if $\nu(E) := \int fd\mu$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

If I have a measure $\nu(E) := \int_E fd\mu$ where $f$ is $\mu$-integrable. Then is it true that for $g$ that is $\nu$-integrable we have $\int g d\nu = \int fg d\mu$. Reading a bit about this I think it might be linked to the concept of [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20absolute%20continuity%20is,of%20calculus%E2%80%94differentiation%20and%20integration.) but I am not sure if there are condition or why this is the case.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024997/understanding-proposition-3-9-folland-part-2-radon-nikodym-derivative/3025200

Comment: Verify it for a simple function $g$ and then extend to any integrable $g$ using standard arguments.

Comment: I see. If $g = \mathbb{1}_A$ I have $\int gd\nu = \int \mathbb{1}_Ad\nu =\nu(A)=\int_A f d\mu = \int f \mathbb{1}_A d\mu$